# Sigma-algebra generated by a sequence with zeros

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Let $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of zero mean random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. Suppose that there is some $i_0>0$ such that  $x_i=0$ for all $i\geq i_0$.

Does the following hold (the second equality) ?
$$\sigma(x_i: i\in\mathbb{N})=\sigma(\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\sigma(x_i))=\sigma(\cup_{i=1}^{i_0-1}\sigma(x_i))$$

**My understanding**

I believe yes since $\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\sigma(x_i)=(\cup_{i=1}^{i_0-1}\sigma(x_i))\cup (\cup_{i\geq i_0}\sigma(x_i))$ and $\cup_{i\geq i_0}\sigma(x_i)=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$. This latter is the trivial sigma-algebra and is contained in $\cup_{i=1}^{i_0-1}\sigma(x_i)$.

Comment: Yes, what you have done is correct.

Comment: ... and least if the index $i_0$ does not depend on $\omega$, i.e. if $x_i(\omega)=0$ for all $i \geq i_0$ **and all $\omega \in \Omega$**. In case that $i_0$ depends on $\omega$ (i.e. for each $\omega$ there exists some $i_0$ such that $x_i(\omega)=0$ for all $i \geq i_0$), your reasoning does not work.

Comment: @saz thank you. Nice observation

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've seen your name repeatly giving feedbacks to my attempts. I'm really grateful to you!